# What is a ~$ office file?

Tags: ms-office

My system creates a copy of every office file like ppt, doc etc. with the same extension but the name changes in a way that it is prefixed by ~$. This clone file can't be opened and gets deleted on its own as soon as the original file is closed. Is it due to any kind of virus or something else?

Comment: That file contains metadata to provide more descriptive information if another session (or another user) wants to access the same file and it sees a lock. It is harmless.

Comment: It's just a lock file. Other applications do this as well (openoffice, libreoffice, ...)